# Products not importing via CSV - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3, import-products, product-import

I'm trying to import products on Magento 2.2.3 via the **System > Data Transfer > Import method**.

I've selected '**Add / Update**' from '**Import Behaviour**' and the file imports successfully.

But, none of the products are showing on the frontend, backend or in the database.

What could be wrong?

I downloaded the sample file it gives you and filled it in with our products.

If you want me to supply my excel sheet, can you point me in a place to where I can host it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix this.

The issue was my excel not saving the document properly to UTF8 (Comma Delimited).

I had to open the .csv using notepad and resaving it into UTF 8 that way.